# Create DBF file from DataTable in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a fully populated DataTable and I am trying to write the entire DataTable to a dbase file. I am trying to use DBase 3 and am in VB.net. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to use the [SocialExplorer/FastDBF](https://github.com/SocialExplorer/FastDBF) open source .NET library for reading and writing DBF files.

You will find an [example](https://github.com/SocialExplorer/FastDBF/blob/master/TestDbfLib/Program.cs) showing how dbf-files can be created. FastDBF doesn’t use `DataTable` so. The example is in C# sharp, however, it's the same principle in VB.